# setInterval contador JavaScript ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

Quiero hacer una cuenta regresiva para que cada 10 segundos muestre una palabra distinta, este contador arranca una vez que el usuario de play y si llega a 0 se reinicia y muestra otra palabra. Estará de esa forma hasta que el usuario de Stop. y hay un botón para siguiente palabra el cual al darle cambia la palabra automáticamente y reinicia el contador. El código que hice da muchos errores y se buguea

```
const [palabras] = useState(["Azul", "Collar", "Orgullo", "Tarjeta"]);
const [palabraRandom, setPalabraRandom] = useState("Random");
const [contador, setContador] = useState(10);
const [play, setPlay] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    actualizarContador();
}, [play, contador]);

const actualizarContador = () => {
    if (contador < 0) {
        setContador(10);
        aleatorio();
    }
    if (!play) {
        clearInterval(intervalo);
        setContador(10);
    }
    const intervalo = setInterval(() => {
        setContador(contador - 1);
    }, 1000);
};

const aleatorio = () => {
    let i = palabras[Math.floor(Math.random() * palabras.length)];

    setPalabraRandom(i);
};

const siguientePalabra = () => {
    aleatorio();
    setContador(10);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías adaptar el siguiente código a lo que necesitas para la versión de React, te presento una versión funcional en HTML, lo que es importante es que almacenes el **id** del intervalo para cancelarlo cuando el usuario haga click en algún botón

```js
const palabras = ["Azul", "Collar", "Orgullo", "Tarjeta"]
let timerId;

function randomRange(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}


function startAnimation() {
    const container = document.querySelector('#text')

    timerId = setInterval(() => {
    container.innerText = palabras[Math.trunc(randomRange(0, palabras.length))];
  }, 1000);
}

function cancelAnimation() {
    clearInterval(timerId);
}

startAnimation();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div style="height: 30px;">
<span class="badge rounded-pill bg-dark" id="text" style="color: white"></span>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="startAnimation()">
  Iniciar
</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="cancelAnimation()">
  Cancelar
</button>
```

Comment: Puede funcionar y lo adapté al código pero la variable global que tiene el Id del setInterval no me la reconoce cuando le asigno un valor dentro de la función startAnimation(). Si le quito el signo de asignar no hay ningún problema pero necesito asignarle eso que hiciste tu

Answer (score 1):

Estas creando un loop infinito en el useEffect porque al tener como dependencia a *contador* al momento de llamar a la función *actualizarContador* actualizas a *contador* que al cambiar llama a useEffect que a su vez cambia el contador y  así sucesivamente.

Una manera de lograr la funcionalidad esperada seria primero quitar a contador como dependencia de useEffect y usando setTimeout en lugar de setInterval

```
   useEffect(() => {      
          play && actualizarContador();
      }, [play]);
```

Para que puedas limpiar el *timeout* con las funciones de *actualizarContador* y *SiguientePalabra* podrías crear un state

```
const [time, setTime] = useState(null)
```

Luego en actualizar contador cambiar *play* a *false* al inicio y luego a *true* al terminar el setTimeout de esta manera llamara nuevamente a useEffect.

```
const actualizarContador = () => {     
      if (contador < 0) {         
          setContador(10);
          aleatorio();
          setPlay(false)
      }
      if (!play) {          
          clearTimeout(time);
          setContador(10);
      }
      setPlay(false)

      setTime(setTimeout(() => {
          if(contador >=0) setContador(contador - 1);
          setPlay(true)
      }, 1000));
  };
```

y en siguiente palabra

```
 const siguientePalabra = () => {
    clearTimeout(time)
    aleatorio();
    setPlay(true)
    setContador(10);
  };
```